# Unexpected assert behavior

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin Android so in writing tests these asserts unexpectedly pass:

```
import org.junit.Test

assert("x".equals("y"))
assert("x" == "y")
```

but this does fail:

```
import junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
assertEquals("x", "y")
```

So I reviewed string structural comparisons.

And then found that this also passes:

```
assert(false)
```

Looks like org.junit.Test comes by default in a new project via:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

So now I'm wondering what's the correct testImplementation package to sync with. Am I using the wrong one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the doc for `assert` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html):

> Throws an AssertionError if the value is false and runtime assertions
>   have been enabled on the JVM using the -ea JVM option.

What you should do is to use `Assert.assertTrue` or `Assert.assertEquals` from `org.junit` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You're using [`kotlin.assert`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html) which are only enabled when platform assertions are enabled. The checks that you say should cause errors simply are never executed.

Either run it with the `-ea` (enable assertsions) JVM parameter or use `assertEquals` which is the usual test framework name since `assert` is a keyword in java.

Answer (score -3):

Looking for inside documentation, assertEquals hasn't two String parameters to compare. It only receive generic Objects:

> assertEquals(java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual) =>
>   Asserts that two objects are equal.

Strings should be compared using `.equals(String)` method due using Objects have differents address memory access, so these are differents despite of they have same content.

**:: Edit ::**

To have the sames Objects type of Strings you should use `.clone()` method. It returns same content and same references from original object.